# The priority of locomotion in Aristotelian physics - what are qualities then?

Tags: aristotle

Reading through the Physics I came across a passage whose significance I had not adequately appreciated, in VIII.7 260b7-14, when he's arguing for the causal and temporal priority of locomotion to alteration and increase.

"All affections have their origin in condensation and rarefaction: thus heavy and light, soft and hard, hot and cold, are considered to be forms of density and rarity. But condensation and rarefaction are combination and separation, processes in virtue of which substances are said to become and perish; and in being combined and separated things must change in respect of place. And further, when a thing is increased or decreased its magnitude changes in respect of place."

If all affection is reducible to locomotion, where does that leave affective qualities? How is a thing's being white, or our perceiving that it is white, really different from the parts being rearranged in place, or some external parts supervening, in the thing and in our brains? Wouldn't the difference become merely verbal, or an accident of animal perception, that we see one thing as being "here or there" and another as being "such"?

But of course this problem does not overturn quality in general, since the other genera of quality are either the coming to be of a substantial form, or depend on a relation with two terms, as discussed in VII.3, and so these are not produced by alteration except per accidens.